# Sort table data on weekday

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server table like this:

`table(Id, DestId, WeekDay)` 
WeekDay is nvarchar holding values like `Monday`, `Tuesday`, `Wednesday`, etc. Here `Id` and `Weekday` are composite primary keys. I want the result of select query to be sorted on `WeekDay` order, i.e. Monday should come before Tuesday and Wednesday and so on.

Write now `Select * from table where Id=1001` gives records sorted on WeekDays Alphabetic order

Comment: Do you have a full date field in the table or only day names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution here: http://dbaspot.com/sqlserver-faq/393109-order-day-week.html

You have to make a case structure in your SQL statement like this one:

```
select *
from table
ORDER BY case WeekDay when 'Monday' then 1
    when 'Tuesday' then 2
    when 'Wednesday' then 3
    when 'Thursday' then 4
    when 'Friday' then 5
    when 'Saturday' then 6
    when 'Sunday' then 7
    else 8
END
;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY CHARINDEX(LEFT(WeekDay,3),'MonTueWedThuFriSatSun')
```

`CHARINDEX(LEFT(WeekDay,3),'MonTueWedThuFriSatSun')` will return the index position. If you want to **sort from Sunday**, the you can change the string to `'SunMonTueWedThuFriSat'`

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
Select
 CASE WeekDay
   WHEN 'Monday' THEN 1
   WHEN 'Tuesday' THEN 2
   WHEN 'Wednesday' THEN 3
   WHEN 'Thursday' THEN 4
   WHEN 'Friday' THEN 5
   WHEN 'Saturday' THEN 6
   WHEN 'Sunday' THEN 7 End
 AS SortWeekday
FROM [TABLE]
WHERE Id = 1001
OrderBy SortWeekday
```

Answer (score 0):

Having weekday as plain text in a table is not really good practice. You should use a smallint to store the Weekday value instead. Having that said. Here is a solution.

By making a script to test different combinations, I came up with this combination of Weekday and 2 other characters.

```
SELECT WeekDay 
FROM
  (VALUES('Monday'),('Tuesday'),('Wednesday'),('Thursday'),
         ('Friday'),('Saturday'),('Sunday')) x(WeekDay)
ORDER BY HASHBYTES('SHA1',WeekDay + 'g2')
```

Note it is case sensitive on the days.